# Don't delete cells

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have in the cell is the horizontal scrolling, it created 5 - 10 images that are loaded via the internet.
How better to do? Save pictures in the array and the number of  scroll position or simply don't remove the cells from memory?
Cells to about 50.
It is better if not just remove the cell from the memory, tell me how to do it?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
     return [self.conteinerHotels count];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [LazyTableImages](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html).

This sample demonstrates a multi-stage approach to loading and displaying a 
UITableView. It begins by loading the relevant text from the RSS feed so the table can load
as quickly as possible, then downloads the app images for each row asynchronously 
so the UI is more responsive.